# How to change Zimbra Web UI URL Path? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, zimbra, zimbra-talk

I am new to Zimbra configurations. I have configured my Zimbra on Ubuntu 20.04 and its working fine. but the Web UI opens on my base domain. I want to change the domain.

For Example:
Currently, my web ui opens at `mydomain.com/`

I want to change it from `mydomain.com/` to something like `mydomain.com/webmails` or `webmails.mydomain.com/`.

Please help!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have read a lot of articles but none of them helped me find a solution to my problem. While playing around I was able to solve the problem.

As I am managing my DNS from Cloudflare, hence enabled proxy for my mail domain `domain.com`. by doing so, I was able to load my Zimbra web UI on `mail.domain.com` but the issue arose here is that when you access to mail with `HTTPS` it works fine, but with `HTTP` it shows a 403 forbidden access.

To resolve the predefined issue, I have added a 301 redirection rule in my Nginx conf file and boom everything worked as I needed.

Thanks to the community.